# Laravel: Condition in select dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to get the value of my Select Dropdown list from my view to my controller

Is there any way i can get this? :(

**Here's my dropdown view**

```
{{ Form::select('status', ['All', 'Absent', 'Late', 'Others']) }}
```

**Here's where i want to condition my selected value**

```
    public function filterSummaryStudent()
    {
        if(Input::has('status') == 'All')
        {

      (other codes here)
         }
```

I've been getting a blank page when i call this.. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: you just want to retrieve the dropdown value in the controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the value of select dropdown as associative arrays if you want to check the value as a string. Right now your select dropdown code the value is define using numeric index of the array. When you check the Input::has('status') == 'All', of course laravel will return false.

**Your code**

```
{{ Form::select('status', ['All', 'Absent', 'Late', 'Others']) }}
```

**HTML Output**

```
<select name="status">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="1">Absent</option>
    <option value="2">Late</option>
    <option value="3">Others</option>
</select>
```

**Correct code**

```
{!! Form::select('status', ['All' => 'All', 'Absent' => 'Absent', 'Late' => 'Late', 'Others' => 'Others']) !!}
```

**HTML Output**

```
<select name="status">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="absent">Absent</option>
    <option value="late">Late</option>
    <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
```

If you write like the above code you can check the select dropdown like this.

```
if(Input::has('status') == 'All') {
    // Your code
}
```